# Issue with getting value from form in Java - Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, apache, jakarta-ee, tomcat7

Hey guys I have this form that is sent over to a roaster that will get the names that were entered into the form fields in a Java project - I am using a Apache Tomcat v7.0 to run it(servlet) For some reason though when I am in the roaster file it tells me that the methods defined in the form file do not exist.

CODE for form:

```
<form action="Band_roster" method="post">
  <table cellspacing="5" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Band 1:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name=Band1.setbname()></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Band 2:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name=Band2.setbname()></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Band 3:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name=Band3.setbname()></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Band 4:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name=Band4.setbname()></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Band 5:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name=Band5.setbname()></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Band 6:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name=Band6.setbname()></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Band 7:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name=Band7.setbname()></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Band 8:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name=Bandb.setbname()></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><br><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </form>
```

CODE for roaster:

```
<table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Band1:</td>
            <td><%= Band1.getBname() %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Band2:</td>
            <td><%= Band2.getBname() %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Band3:</td>
            <td><%= Band3.getBname() %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Band4:</td>
            <td><%= Band4.getBname() %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Band5:</td>
            <td><%= Band5.getBname() %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Band6:</td>
            <td><%= Band6.getBname() %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Band7:</td>
            <td><%= Band7.getBname() %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Band8:</td>
            <td><%= Band8.getBname() %></td>
        </tr>

    </table>

    <p>Ready to Rock</p>

    <form action="Band.jsp" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

the roaster file is the one that I am getting the errors - Band8.getBname() tells me it cannot be resolved, same with every Band'number' in the tr's.

Let me know if this makes sense and thanks for the help!

Comment: the roaster is the file it goes to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I assume that what you have shown us are snippets of source code from two different jsp pages, and that the html rendered by the first jsp page somehow posts to something that renders the second jsp page.

However, you don't mention whether you are using a web framework of some sort, writing servlets, or what...perhaps you could enlighten us.

Anyway, you seem to be missing a few basic concepts:

The first jsp page (with the form) does not appear to be something that would work.

Presumably, the Band1, Band2, etc. objects are defined at the top of the first jsp page, but you don't show that.

The syntax for the input fields in the first jsp page, `<input type="text" name=Band1.setbname()>` is incorrect. Assuming that, for example, Band1 is an object that is defined in the page, the input field should be something like: `<input type="text" name="${Band1.bname}">`, which, if Band1 had a getBname() method, would initialize the value of the input field to the result of calling that method. However, from your use of 'setbname', I'm guessing that you expect this to take the value of the input field and use it to set the value of a property in Band1. Unfortunately, that's not how it works. What happens is that the values in the form fields are sent as request parameters to the second page.

In the second jsp page, you have the correct syntax for outputting the values of Band1.bname, assuming that Band1 is defined in that page. I'm guessing that it isn't. You would need to somehow convert the request parameters to instances of Band, or whatever class Band1 is.

Typically, one would not POST to another jsp page (though you can). This sort of thing is usually handled by a servlet, or better yet, a Controller class in a web framework like Struts or Spring MVC. Then, the servlet or Controller would typically render the jsp page, sending it the Band objects to reference.

Comment: The first page is a html page, the second is a .jsp file. The Band1, they are not defined in the .jsp file(bottom code part) They are defined in the form.  So I am trying to figure out how to send the data from the form over to the roaster.jsp page so I can display the values sent form the form.

Comment: As I said, the form values would show up as request parameters in the jsp page. You get them with request.getParameter("parameterName"), where "parameterName" is the name of the associated form field. So, for example, request.getParameter("Band1"). But since you have form names like "Band3.setbname()", I'm not sure what you're going to get. I would change the form parameter names to something like "band1name", and use quotes.

Comment: Ya I did that but now it tells me `The method getParameter(String) is undefined for the type __2F_finalprojectfor_5F_client_2F_WebContent_2F_Band_5F_roster_2E_jsp`  Also I appreciate the help!

Comment: it's not getParameter("parameterName"), it's request.getParameter("parameterName")

Comment: okay so it worked except for some reason when I go and hit submit button to be sent to page that gets values I get a 404 error, I notice in the address bar it tells me /band_roaster and once I add the .jsp it works fine and goes to page, but without any values.

Comment: make sure that your 'form' element looks like: *<form action="band_roaster.jsp" method="post">* and then try it again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21109/discussion-between-greybeardedgeek-and-david-biga)